# filebeat configuration to send logfile to ELK which is installed in cloudfoundry

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, cloud-foundry, filebeat, elk

I've been working to install ELK stack in CloudFoundry and sending log files from other local server by using filebeat.
I have successfully installed ELK in CloudFoundry and able to see sample messages. 
Now I am trying to send log files from local server by using filebeat. Can you suggest how to configure filebeat to send log files from local server to Logstash in CloudFoundry?

Comment: This question is not really about programming. Maybe https://serverfault.com is a better place for this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure the Logstash output in Filebeat for this, specifying the host & port for target logstash:

```
#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["127.0.0.1:5044"]
```

On the logstash side, you'll need to add a *beats* input to the config:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}" 
  }
}
```

Read the complete documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html).